# best way to send data(given in Bytes) to a process in openMPI?

Tags: c++, c, ipc, mpi, openmpi

I am doing like this ,
Suppose i need to send temp amount of bytes to root process  :

```
var char*;
var=new char[temp];
MPI_Isend(&temp,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request[0]);
MPI_Isend(var,temp,MPI_BYTE,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request[1]);
```

and on the root process ,i am writing this code ,

```
MPI_Recv(&temp,1,MPI_INT,i,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[0]);
var=new char[temp];
MPI_Recv(var,temp,MPI_BYTE,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[1]);
```

I am able to receive temp(amount of data bytes to be transfered) at root process and seeing error of truncated message for the next part  ?

Comment: What type is `temp`? How many bytes is the message? How many bytes are you receiving?

Comment: temp is an integer . this is a virtual data (say 1000 bytes which may not have any value rather the space) .

Comment: i suppose now this works for me.Now the thing i want to ask from you is : i have several steps of a big source code (each step has a virtual computation time and virtual communication data) . i need to test this by make the code sleep for the computation time and transferring the data equivalent to the communication data . can you suggest some configuration models to the same ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373970/what-are-the-models-to-distribute-tasks-in-processes-using-openmpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving from the wrong location:

```
MPI_Recv(var,temp,MPI_BYTE,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[1]);
                           ^
```

You should be receiving from (presumably), the `i` process.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Two things were not matching and hence the message truncation  :) Thank you , u save my time .

Comment: Now the thing i want to ask from you is : i have several steps of a big source code (each step has a virtual computation time and virtual communication data) . i need to test this by make the code sleep for the computation time and transferring the data equivalent to the communication data . can you suggest some configuration models to the same ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to send the number of elements as a separate message. MPI provides a mechanism that allows the program to peek into the message queue and to obtain the message size before receiving it.

Sender:

```
char *var = new char[temp];
MPI_Send(var, temp, MPI_BYTE, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Receiver:

```
MPI_Status status;
int temp;
// Probe for matching message without receiving it
MPI_Probe(i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
// Get the number of data elements in the message
MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &temp);
char *var = new char[temp];
MPI_Recv(var, temp, MPI_BYTE, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

This is a far more optimal way to communicate arrays of varying size.