# what are the models to distribute tasks in processes using openMPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, ipc, mpi

The thing i want to ask from you is : i have several steps of a big source code (each step has a virtual computation time and virtual communication data,i am taking only virtual as i wants to model the latency and somehow i managed to measure them throughout the source code) . I need to test this by make the code sleep for the computation time and transferring the data equivalent to the communication data . Can you suggest some configuration models to the same ? My aim is to minimizing the overall execution time of the program and thus obviously i want to diminish the overhead that the process can have.

The simplest that strikes my mind are :

---

1. Do the computation on all processes and send the virtual data by making asynchronous call to the root processes
2. Do the same with Synchronous call .
3. Assume the communication time is linear with the communication data . Use some algorithm to divide the tasks formerly to each process (inspired from load balancing)
4. Start from the first task with the root process and sends data to the next process , do sleep on that process and show on.

can you please give me some idea or verify ,if this strategy makes a lot of difference ?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you'd like to do. There are well known patterns in parallel programming and most (if not all) of them are well understood in terms of their latency and communication overhead, performance and ability to perform load balancing.

Comment: Can you please make comments on the 4 ways that i explained ? thanks for your support till now.

Comment: Given what you've described, it sounds like you have the intellectual tools to form this analysis yourself. According to the simple latency/bandwidth model you stated, how long does each approach take? It sounds like you're asking us to do a bit of homework for you.