# load balancing in openMPI?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, ipc, openmpi

The thing I want to ask from you is :

I have several steps of a big source code (each step has a virtual computation time and virtual communication data,I am taking only virtual as I want to model the latency and somehow I managed to measure them throughout the source code) . I need to test this by make the code sleep for the computation time and transferring the data equivalent to the communication data .

Can you suggest some configuration models to the same ?

My aim is to minimize the overall execution time of the program and thus obviously I want to diminish the overhead that the process can have.

The simplest things that strike my mind are :

- Do the computation on all processes and send the virtual data by
  making asynchronous call to the root processes
- Do the same with Synchronous call .
- Assume the communication time is linear with the communication data .
- Use some algorithm to divide the tasks formerly to each process
  (inspired from load balancing)
- Start from the first task with the root process and sends data to the
  next process , do sleep on that process and show on.

Can you please give me some idea or verify ,if this strategy makes a lot of difference ?

Comment: Are you asking how to test your LoadBalancer or you want the best way to make it work?

Comment: how to do it ? best way to make it work ?

Comment: The Test or the Code?

Comment: Please, don't post the same question twice. This is simply a repost of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373970/what-are-the-models-to-distribute-tasks-in-processes-using-openmpi).